# Bash code from bash script not working from Python (3.6)

Tags: python, linux, bash, serial-port, python-3.6

I have this small piece of Bash script which enters a character continuosly 12 times to a serial device every 1 millisecond (it is run immediately after a reboot of the device). When I try to run this, it works fine from bash. If I try to run this from Python, with the same logic, it does nothing. Also I tried to simplay call this bash script from python, it still does not work. Here is my bash script:

```
for i in {1..12}
do echo 's' > /dev/ttyUSB2
sleep 0.1
done
```

And the python code I tried to run is:

```
#reboot here
for i in range (1, 12):
    os.popen("echo s > /dev/ttyUSB2")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Also I tried to just invoke the bash script from python

`os.popen("source gotomode.sh")`

where gotomode.sh is the bash script.

What could I be possibly doing wrong?
Is timing different while using python commands os.popen, subprocess.popen, popen2 etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using shell redirection with `os.popen()` but `os.popen()` doesn't spawn a shell. Why not do `with open('/dev/ttyUSB2', 'w') as f: f.write('s')`?

Comment: Actually, `os.popen()` while not being a great choice here... does spawn a shell: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cebe9ee988837b292f2c571e194ed11e7cd4abbb/Lib/os.py#L978

Comment: I had also tried subprocess.call("echo s > /dev/ttyUSB2", shell=True), which did not work.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for your suggestion, but with open('/dev/ttyUSB2', 'w') as f: f.write('s') does not work for me.